# Load page without loading the browser tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I need to load content from another page. The URL should change. But the page shouldn't load. **

Hey guys,

Any hints on how I can achieve something like this? Pls check the following website's contact page. It just loads the content itself on the home page. But the URL changes. How can I do this?  I'm familiar with html,css,js and Laravel PHP.

https://www.division.global/

Comment: See `history.replaceState()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.